# How is AWK found?

Tags: automake

Automake Manual

15.4.2 Use TAP with the Automake test harness
 "the awk program found by AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE to run your TAP-producing
  tests. See the example below for clarification."

TAP requires that a reference to AWK be supplied in AM_TAP_AWK. In the vernacular (or vulgate) no way do the manual instructions instruct. There is no option which informs AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE that a reference to AWK is required, and the manual is opaque on how to find a reference. So, what magic do I have to use to correctly assign a value to AM_TAP_AWK?

(I'm rewriting Section 15 Support for Test Suites for use in future Automake Manuals).

Answer (score 1):

`AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` calls `AC_PROG_AWK` to find `awk`.  This macro is defined by `autoconf.`